# How to write ar & ma terms in dynamic regression/arimax in terms of actual predictors?

Tags: regression, time-series, arima, dynamic-regression

I have done Arimax with response series Y as sales/demand & a set of input series on time series data at monthly level.
The estimates from the arimax model is as shown below.

[image]

I want to now write identify the demand function in the below format only using predictors/input series and not using any of the ar or ma terms of the errors.

Sales=D(intercept,inventory_x,mrp_x,discount_x,discountLagx,promo_x)

My entire objective is to identify the correct demand function.

Questions

1. Please explain how to write demand function without ar & ma terms of error?
   I believe just ignoring the estimates of ar & ma terms of error is not correct. Is this true?
2. Please illustrate the calculation behind forecast() function in arimax
3. Is there a better technique for identifying demand function other than arimax?

Comment: If some one has knowledge in this topic, can you give your thoughts?